# Xamarin Forms MVVMCross how to pass parameter when closing the viewmodel

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin Forms using MVVMCross. One of my view models loads a new ViewModel like this:

```
 public class ViewModelMainForm: BaseViewModel, IMvxViewModel<string>
     {
    
..... some code here .....

public void Prepare(String parameters)
        {
           // should get incidentId HERE****
            
        }

public async void OnShowIncidentForm()
    {
        var result = await _navigation.Navigate(typeof(ViewModelIncidentForm), _selectedItem.EmployeeId);
    }
}
```

Then the new view appears perfect and I can receive the EmployeeId in the `Prepare` method.

```
 public class ViewModelIncidentForm : BaseViewModel, IMvxViewModel<string>
 {

   ..... some code here .....

      public void Prepare(String parameters)
        {
           
            employeeId = parameters.ToString();

            GetEmployeeData(employeeId);

        }

     public void CloseView(int incidentId)
     {

        _navigation.Close(this, incidentId);
     }

 }
```

All this works perfect, the problem is that when I close the ViewModel to pop to the previous ViewModel I don't know how to get the parameter "`incidentId`".

In my main form ViewModel, I already placed a breakpoint into the Prepare method but is not triggered.

Any clue on how to get the parameter sent in the `navigation.Close()` method in my main ViewModel?

Comment: AFAIK, the usual mvvmcross solution is to use their Messaging. Subscribe in OnShowIncidentForm, go to page, when page closes, Publish.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve do you know what is the messaging framework? So I can find a sample?

Comment: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/messenger